# How to get no fixed number params in expressjs 4 router

Tags: regex, express, router, parameters

I need to match a path like: `/asd/xc2/asder4/12edad`. The path is not fixed.

I expect params like: `[asd, xc2, asder4, 12edad]` or object data.

In router, I wrote:

```
router.get('(?:/([0-9a-z\._]+))+', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params);
    res.send('something');
});
```

but I got `{}`. How should I get path params in router?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just keep it simple:

```
router.get('*', function (req, res) {
    var terms = req.url.split('/');
    res.send('something');
});
```

Just make sure this route is defined last, after your other less wildcard-y routes so it doesn't match by mistake.

Comment: thx，that's very helpful!Can I understand I can;t get no fixed params through regex in router path?

Comment: Yes you can use a regex. Split is better. The code is clear and short. Done. Move on.

Comment: I mean I can not use regex in this case. Is that right?